# Windows 8.1 extending displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, resolution, display-driver, extended-desktop

I have an old Inspiron 6400. I want to be  able to extend/duplicate my display over to another monitor, but am unable to do so. I can use either of the monitors when I activate CRT/LCD switch on the lappy, but not both monitors at the same time. I suspect that it might have something to do with the display driver, because Windows 7 used to work fine and the linux on the other partition works fine as well.

I am including some screenshots. The resolution option is locked to 1024x768. The driver being used is the Microsoft basic display driver, I think the driver should be ATI. I have already tried updating the driver from windows update but got nada.

Hope someone can help.

[image: Device Manager Page]
[image: Display Adapter Properties]
[image: Screen Resolution Page]

Comment: Some hardware can only support a single display.  it is possible that your laptop can only mirror or display on the external port.  it might not exist as a secondary display adapter.  Not sure in this case, but if it is an older laptop, odds are, it will not.

Comment: @MikeAWood, I have already mentioned that extending and mirroring was working fine on Windows 7 and Linux (earlier on XP too).

Comment: Somehow I missed that when I read the question.  FWIW, I have run into some issues running Windows 8 on my older Lenovo X200 laptop.  In my instance, things like OpenGL are no longer supported even though the graphics adapter has a valid driver and it was supported under Windows 7.  (Intel opted to not include OpenGL support with the WHQL driver included with Windows 8).  Answer still might be you are out of luck.  But I'd try to see if you can get the Windows 7 driver to load and see if it functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the drivers at last. By the way these are for ATI Mobility Raedon X1400 on Win7 x64, but also works well on Win 8 & 8.1.

http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2011/06/20232705_a9cff6669e7ea32aba78f5d4f87e9a8c5f253f02.cab

Cheers!